# iPhone/iPad Camera Overlay View AutoRotation Issue UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

According to Apple, we must not subclass the `UIImagePickerController` class. From the docs:

> Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode
>   only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support
>   subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not
>   be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
>   cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
>   information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
>   and your code.

But If we want to overlay a view on the camera, we can do so as follows:

```
imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = overlayView
```

After implementing the camera overlay view, The view adjusts itself automatically in iPads. However, this is not the case with the iPhones.

Query:
Can we set the autorotation of the cameraOverlayView in iPhone as in iPad?

If not, what is the optimum way of rotating the cameraOverlayView with `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `UIImagePickerController` and can instantiate it. Apple saying that you should not subsclass it is for other reason. You can not change default controls of `UIImagePickerController` like swap camera, flash turn on off, take photo or video etc. For that you have to create `overlay view` and should set as `cameraOverlayView` of `UIImagePickerController`. That's it, otherwise you can subclass `UIImagePickerController`.

So, now solution for your issue :

Subclass `UIImagePickerController` and in that class implement below two methods like,

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

    return NO;
}
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

and then instantiate that class instead of `UIImagePickerController`.

and your orientation issue for your overlayview will be solved. It will always remain in portrait mode.